# How to resolve this error in AKS deployments

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-aks, azure-container-registry

I am deploying my apps to AKS using Azure DevOps through Helm Charts.

Everything was working fine until my deployments have started failing all of a sudden.

In a deployment, 2 out of 3 or 1 out of 2 pods are able to pull the image from ACR & they are getting started. But the remaining pods give following error:

> 2m9s        Warning   Failed
> pod/podname-5f6d498f6b-wzx5h       Failed to pull image
> "acrname.azurecr.io/repo/image-name:1.0.73": rpc error:
> code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image
> "acrname.azurecr.io/repo/image-name:1.0.73": failed to
> resolve reference
> "acrname.azurecr.io/repo/image-name:1.0.73": failed to do
> request: Head
> "https://acrname.azurecr.io/v2/repo/image-name/manifests/1.0.73":
> dial tcp: lookup prd255acr01.azurecr.io on [::1]:53: read udp
> [::1]:34880->[::1]:53: read: connection refused

I can login to the ACR, AKS is able to pull the images from ACR & I can see the image pulled from ACR when I do `docker images`

How can I resolve this error? It is failing all of my deployments of all the apps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue is reflected here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1988119

rebooting pool nodes fixes issue.